# How to copy complete div element to the clipboard using Javasript or Typescript only?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I have the html div element something like :

```
<div id="divTest" style='background-color:grey;'>
Hello
</div>
```

I want to copy the complete div element and not just the content "Hello".

This is what I tried but it is copying only content :

```
var element = document.getElementById("divTest");

var selection = window.getSelection();
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNode(element);
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
document.execCommand("Copy");
```

If anyone has any idea of how to copy the complete div element ??

Thanks

Comment: You mean div's innerHTML to copy?

Comment: What you are expecting when you will copy the `div` in your clipboard

Comment: @blacksheep I want to paste the complete ```div``` then

Comment: @BiploveLamichhane no I mean complete ```div``` to copy

Answer (score 0):

This is how it can be done (check it out all who gave negative mark without even thinking of solution)

```
<div id='myTestELement' style='background-color:grey;'>
Hello
</div>

<input type="text"  id="myInput">
```

```
var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
copyText.value = document.getElementById("myTestELement").outerHTML;
copyText.select();
copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
document.execCommand("copy");
```

This will copy the html element in the form of string to the textInput value .

Answer (score 0):

You can use navigator interface also.

```
const element = document.querySelector('#divTest');
const promise = navigator.clipboard.writeText(element.outerHTML)
promise.then(
            () => console.log('Success'), 
            () => console.log('Failure')
         )
```

This is a cleaner than approach than `execCommand`, and Firefox has declared `document.execCommand` an obsolete method.
In order to completely understand the `navigator.clipboard`, go through [Permissions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API) and understand *secure context* and *user's consent*

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to copy event listener also ??